# How do I create a one-to-one relationship in WCF RIA Services for LightSwitch?

Tags: c#, wcf-ria-services, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I've come a long way in my understanding of WCF RIA Services and Microsoft LightSwitch, but now I'm at a loss. I'll use `Animal` and `Dog` as examples. I actually want a *zero-or-one*-to-one relationship, not every Animal will necessarily be/have Dog.

First I create a one-to-one relationship in my database that I want to use with RIA Services. Then I update the Model.edmx file in my RIA Services project like usual. The issue is instead of this giving me access to `ObjectContext.Dogs` as I was expecting, that doesn't exist, and instead Animal has been given the extra properties of Dog. Apparently one-to-one relationships are specially handled in this manner, which *seems* like it's intended to be helpful, but I'm having much difficulty working with it this way.

My RIA Services classes look like this:

```
public class RiaDog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PackLeaderId { get; set; }

    [Association("RiaAnimal_RiaDog", "Id", "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public RiaAnimal Animal { get; set; }
}

public class RiaAnimal
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Association("RiaAnimal_RiaDog", "Id", "Id", IsForeignKey = false)]
    public RiaDog Dog { get; set; }
}
```

Unless there's some sort of magic one-to-one data annotation attribute I'm not aware of, I have to write CRUD methods for `RiaDog` just like `RiaAnimal` and every other class. This gets pretty awkward given the fact that ObjectContext.Dogs doesn't exist, I have to work through Animal:

```
[Query(IsDefault = true)]
public IQueryable<RiaDog> GetAllDogs() {
    var report = from animal in ObjectContext.Animals
                    where animal.PackLeader != null
                    select new RiaDog
                    {
                        Id = animal.Id,
                        PackLeaderId = animal.Dog.PackLeaderId,
                    };
    return report;
}
```

Already this feels strange, I must use a where clause on one of the Dog properties Animal was given to isolate out the dogs.

With some simple creativity I can get the insert, update, and delete methods functional:

```
public void InsertDog(RiaDog riaDog) {
    var animal = ObjectContext.Animals.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == riaDog.Id);
    animal.PackLeader = ObjectContext.PackLeaders.FirstOrDefault(pl => pl.Id == riaDog.PackLeaderId);
    riaDog.Animal.Dog = riaDog;
}

public void UpdateDog(RiaDog rd) {
    var animal = ObjectContext.Animals.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == riaDog.Id);
    animal.PackLeader = ObjectContext.PackLeaders.FirstOrDefault(pl => pl.Id == riaDog.PackLeaderId);
}

public void DeleteDog(RiaDog rd) {
}
```

In `UpdateAnimal()` I use the backreference I set in `InsertDog()` and add:

```
if (riaAnimal.Dog == null)
    riaAnimal.PackLeader = null;
```

I also have Dog set to cascade delete with Animal on the database.

In the LightSwitch front-end I have this on the RiaDog entity:

```
partial void AnimalType_Changed() {
    if (AnimalType != null && AnimalType.Name == "Dog" && this.Dog == null)
        this.Dog == new RiaDog();
    else if (this.Dog != null && (AnimalType == null || AnimalType.Name != "Dog"))
        this.Dog = null;
}
```

The problem I'm having is if I change the type to Dog, save, change it back to something else, save, then change it to Dog again and save, I receive the error: `The context is already tracking a different entity with the same resource Uri.`

---

I've learned to handle other tracking errors:

- When entities are created in the code-behind client-side, they need
  unique ids to be properly tracked client-side.
- In any insert methods in WCF RIA Services, the entity's client id must be set to the real id after the database generates it, e.g.:

```
public void InsertRiaEntity(RiaEntity re) {
    var entity = new Entity();
    entity.SomeProperty = re.SomeProperty;
    entity.AnotherProperty = re.AnotherProperty;
    ObjectContext.Entities.AddObject(entity);
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
    // essential for client<->server tracking
    re.Id = entity.Id;
}
```

---

However I don't know how to solve this current tracking error. Really I feel like I'm taking the wrong approach and I'm looking for an expert's advice on how you're supposed to code one-to-one or *one-or-zero*-to-one relationships in WCF RIA Services for Microsoft LightSwitch.

*I've actually managed to get this all working with a one to many relationship, and in short and reasonable enough code that it seems "correct", so this variation should be achievable.*

Comment: Given up for the time being. Using my working one-to-many solution instead, even though it's not the appropriate relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightSwitch doesn't actually support one-to-one relationships, so even if you had been successful in your RIA service, it wouldn't have worked in LightSwitch anyway.

The work-around is to create a relationship with a multiplicity of zero-to-many, or one-to-many (as you ended up doing). You have to "enforce" the one-to-one in your validation, or code.

Comment: I don't understand why but the problem went away. Now I can access "ObjectContext.Dogs" after updating the model from a database with a one-to-one relationship just fine. I didn't notice until just now.